# Akka streams combine sources, sources appear to start simultaneously

Tags: scala, akka-http, akka-stream

Im using  Source.combine in Akka streams.  I noticed that all of the sources appear to start at the same time at the beginning of the graph lifecycle and buffer some input before pausing and resuming in the order of the source.combine list.

```
val singletonSources = builder.add(
  Source.combine( 
    Source.single(("TABLE HEADER")),             
    actorSource1.map(_ ... toString), //a source using ask ? to an actor                       
    Source.single("ETC"),             
    HttpSource1.map(x=> bytes... to string),                     
    Source.single("ETC"),             
    actorSource2.map(_ ... toString), //a source using ask ? to an actor                  
    Source.single("ETC"),             
    HttpSource2.map(x=> bytes... to string),              
  )(Concat(_)))
```

I have sources coming from HttpRequests as well as actors with ask ? but both types appear to "buffer" some input when the graph is run.  I do see they each wait to resume in the correct order but for http requests, unless I put them at the beginning of the sources list before long running requests I get an Akka tcp timeout exception as the connection appears to wait for the incoming data.

Comment: what's the question???

Comment: I apologize if the question was unclear. I can't edit my post or I would attach images.  I am getting a
`akka.stream.scaladsl.TcpIdleTimeoutException: TCP idle-timeout encountered on connection to [...], no bytes passed in the last 1 minute`.  How can I handle this?  Here is my theory: I believe this is being caused by the position of HttpSource1 in the combine list.  Since it is after ActorSource1 (which takes a couple of minutes to finish), it is timing out as its request is still sent when the graph runs although it appears to wait (and fails) to receive the http response

Answer (score 1):

Change the `combine` strategy to `Merge`.

According to the [Doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stages-overview.html)

> **concat**
>
> emits: when the current stream has an element available; if the current
>   input completes, it tries the next one
>
> **merge**
>
> emits: when one of the inputs has an element available

In other words, with `concat` strategy, it will the rest of the sources will never get chance to be processed if the 1st source never finishes.

So, a correct way will be:

```
val singletonSources = builder.add(
  Source.combine
    Source.single(("TABLE HEADER")),
    actorSource1.map(_ ... toString),
    Source.single("ETC"),
    HttpSource1.map(x=> bytes... to string),
    Source.single("ETC"),
    actorSource2.map(_ ... toString), //a source using ask ? to an actor
    Source.single("ETC"),
    HttpSource2.map(x=> bytes... to string),
    )(Merge(_)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the Sources using a foldLeft:

```
val sourceList = List( Source single "TABLE HEADER",
                       actorSource1.map ..., 
                       ...
                     )


val oneSourceToRuleThemAll : Source[String, _] = 
  (Source.empty[String] /: sourceList)(_ ++ _)
```

Comment: What if the 1st stream never completes, the second source will never be emitted?